Azure Pipelines - restrict a pipeline from being run to a specific user
I am working in Azure Pipelines and I am trying to figure out how to configure a pipeline so that only a specific user can run it. Not anyone else. Can you point me in the right direction?

Did the below answer help?

You can manage the pipelines permissions in the Azure DevOps portal by clicking the Manage security option (next to the Run pipeline button):

